# Saving and reading txt file when app closed and opened

Tags: java, android, file

Now I have app which save and read some text into `.txt` file by button. How can I make that app save file after app closed and reading file when app opened automatically, without any click on buttons?

```
public class mAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button btn_read, btn_save;
private TextView textView;
private String txt = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveFile();
        }
    });
    btn_read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            readFile();
            textView.setText(txt);
        }
    });
}
public String readFile() {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/TEST");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, "file.txt");
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int size = fis.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        fis.read(buffer);
        fis.close();
        txt = new String(buffer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.this, "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return txt;
}

public void saveFile() {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/TEST");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(myDir, "file.txt");
    if (file.exists()){ file.delete();}
    try {
        String sometxt = "Hello world";
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(out);
        pw.println(sometxt);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Android does not have a simple "app closed" concept. Save the data *when the data changes*.

Comment: when app is closed `onPause()` & `onDestroy()` is called, do code for save file in both method, and for read do code in `onCreate()` method.

Comment: When i use onDestroy() method, it calls when app open too and does not work correctly

Comment: Create a BaseClass Parent Activity and save your file there.! 
like BaseActivty extends AppCompatActivity

mAcitivity extends BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

You can use your MainActivity lifecycle callbacks to begin your I/O operations directly, or start `BoundService` which will operate them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting your saveFile() method inside stop() lifecycle method, and putting your readFile() method inside start() lifecycle method. Activity will automatically call start() method once the application starts and it will call stop() method once the applicqtion closes/terminates.